# Node.js How to send error message from express router to web console

Tags: node.js, express-router

In my application I am placing a http request and everything working fine in happy scenario. But when I gave wrong data to populate error deliberately, it shows error in node.js server console but does not send the error message to web console.

In my Angularjs I am placing a $http request as below , in angular controller function.

```
$http({
    url: '/startprocess',
    method: "POST",
    data: {host: 'XX.XX.XX.XXX', user: 'XX', pass: 'YYYY'},
    crossDomain: true,
    //timeout: 1,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','charset' : 'utf-8'}
    }).then(function(response) {                                    
                console.log('success in startprocess');
                $scope.mydata = response;   
    }, function(response) {
        console.log('error in startprocess');
        console.log(response);                          
    });
```

Handling this request in `app.js`

```
var startprocess = require('./routes/startprocess');        
app.use('/startprocess', startprocess);
```

In route folder i have `startprocess.js`  that has below code,

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');
router.post('/startprocess', function(req, res){
    ssh = new SSH({
            host: req.body.host,
            user: req.body.user,
            pass: req.body.pass
        });

    ssh.exec('ls', {
        out: function(stdout) {
            console.log(stdout); 
        }
    }).start();

    ssh.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('In Start, something went wrong.');
        console.log(err);
        //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send({ data: err }) 
        ssh.end();
    });
});
```

Please suggest me to better way of error handling. I want to display some alert if error received. I noticed that in case of error it shows error on server console `In Start, something went wrong.` but shows "`success in startprocess`" in chrome console.

Thanks

Comment: `res.status(404).send();` Just get the status code in there and things will get sorted as you want them to. The actual error object or message is less important. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Here is a same question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209347/sending-an-error-to-client-as-callback-of-http-request/42210385#42210385

Comment: Thanks @giankotarola. It worked. you made my day. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The two callbacks you have provided are success and error callbacks. The error callback will occur if the response code is not between 200 and 299. By default, the error code is 200, so you need to set the response code as `res.status(400)` or similar before you call `res.send`.

Therefore, the `{ data: err }` object you're creating is probably in the `response` variable in your first callback.